# JS how to remove elements from array when i use array as map

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I have js array and i use it as map it is dynamic ( in this example it is not ) 
So i dont know how many elements it will have .
i want to remove all the elements included the one found
This is the final view of the array after loop

```
movmet_sequence_history:[]
movmet_sequence_history["0"] = "A"
movmet_sequence_history["1"] = "B"
movmet_sequence_history["2"] = "C"
movmet_sequence_history["3"] = "D"
....
....
....
....
movmet_sequence_history["20"] = "Z"

if(movmet_sequence_history["2"] == "C")
{
  //HERE I WANT TO REMOVE THE ELEMENTS "2" ,"1" ,"0"
  //Only the movmet_sequence_history["3"] = "D" will remain
}
```

**UPDATE:** 
i  dont what manually delete the right elements 
as i said the array is dynamic and i dont know how many elements will be up to the found one

Comment: why the tag *dictionary*?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove a property from a JavaScript object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-to-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object)

Comment: @user63898 ... even with your last editing the expected processing behavior remains unclear. How exactly does the result of your provided example need to look like? And till now I can't recognize from the example arrays being (mis)used as maps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make them undefined.

```
movmet_sequence_history:[]
movmet_sequence_history["0"] = "A"
movmet_sequence_history["1"] = "B"
movmet_sequence_history["2"] = "C"
movmet_sequence_history["3"] = "D"

if(movmet_sequence_history["2"] == "C")
{
   movmet_sequence_history["0"] = undefined;
   movmet_sequence_history["1"] = undefined;
   movmet_sequence_history["2"] = undefined;
   //Only the movmet_sequence_history["3"] = "D" will remain
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) operator.

> The **`delete` operator** removes a property from an object.

```js
var movement_sequence_history = ["A", "B", "C", "D" ];

if (movement_sequence_history["2"] == "C") {
    delete movement_sequence_history[0];
    delete movement_sequence_history[1];
    delete movement_sequence_history[2];
}

console.log(movement_sequence_history);
```

Comment: This will change index. I guess he needs to keep value `D` at `"3"`

Comment: Though I'm not the downvoter, I'm curious why your answer got -1 and iuliu.net's answer got +1. Both are very similar.

Comment: the question remains, do you like to delete an specifiv item an maintain the index?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array.splice` + `array.fill`. You can give index to array.splice and it will remove all items after that index and return them.

Now you just have to clear all values from original array and merge array returned from splice to it.

#### Sample

```js
var movmet_sequence_history = []
movmet_sequence_history["0"] = "A"
movmet_sequence_history["1"] = "B"
movmet_sequence_history["2"] = "C"
movmet_sequence_history["3"] = "D"

function removeChar(str) {
  var index = movmet_sequence_history.indexOf(str)
  var _t = movmet_sequence_history.splice(index+1);
  movmet_sequence_history.fill(undefined)
  movmet_sequence_history = movmet_sequence_history.concat(_t)

  console.log(movmet_sequence_history)
}
```

```html
<button onclick="removeChar('A')">Remove A</button>
<button onclick="removeChar('B')">Remove B</button>
<button onclick="removeChar('C')">Remove C</button>
<button onclick="removeChar('D')">Remove D</button>
```

Comment: @Downvoter, please comment whats missing. Everyone here is here to learn.